# Array inside an array in request

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have a multiple select box in blade that I send to controller without any problem. 
I am trying to add dynamically more multiple select boxes via JavaScript. What is the correct syntax to achieve that?

My current code:

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="categories[]" class="full-width select2-hidden-accessible select2-multi" data-placeholder="Select Categories" data-init-plugin="select2" tabindex="-1">
```

What I want to make:

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="businesses[1][categories[]]" class="full-width select2-hidden-accessible select2-multi" data-placeholder="Select Categories" data-init-plugin="select2" tabindex="-1">
```

Comment: What do you get when you dd() the request in the controller?

Comment: *"What is the correct syntax to achieve that?"* - adding new selects or getting values from them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add like the following code.

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="businesses[categories][]" class="full-width select2-hidden-accessible select2-multi" data-placeholder="Select Categories" data-init-plugin="select2" tabindex="-1">
```

Comment: Almost what I was looking for. This worked for me:  <select multiple="multiple" name="businesses[1][categories][]" class="full-width select2-hidden-accessible select2-multi" data-placeholder="Select Categories" data-init-plugin="select2" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">

Comment: if this answer is useful for you then please accept my answer.